# How to change the colour of a number if negative or positive?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function which calculates the difference in sales from today to yesterday and this week compared to the week before. How do I change it so that if the value is negative it become RED and if positive or neutral it is GREEN?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="card-footer-transparent text-center pt-2">
<span id="span_day_diff">TBC</span> from previous day
</div>
```

Here is my JS Function:

```
       function dif_day(data) {
         val = data[0]
         var day= []
         day.push(val.DAY_DIFF);
         if (day[0] >= 0) {
            $('#span_day_diff').empty().append("+ " + day.join()); 
         } else {
            $('#span_day_diff').empty().append(day.join()); 
         };
       };
```

Comment: Please do not ask people to write code for you. Post what you have tried and what worked and what didn't.

Comment: You can use your JS to add a class to the the container div which will just turn the colour what you want. for example `.green{color:green;} .red{color:red}`

Answer (score 0):

you need `css` method to set color

```
     if (day[0] >= 0) {
        $('#span_day_diff').empty().append("+ " + day.join()); 
        $('#span_day_diff').css('color', 'green');
     } else {
        $('#span_day_diff').empty().append(day.join()); 
        $('#span_day_diff').css('color', 'red');
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set a style to a label, why don't you use

```
document.getElementById('mySpan').classList.add('positive')
```

---

```
    .positive {
        color: green;
    }

    .negative {
        color: red;
    }

    .default {
        color: gray;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
function dif_day(data) {
         val = data[0]
         var day= [];
         day.push(val.DAY_DIFF);

         if (day[0] >= 0) {
            $('#span_day_diff').empty().append("+ " + day.join()); 
            $('#span_day_diff').style.color = 'green';
         } else {
            $('#span_day_diff').empty().append(day.join()); 
            $('#span_day_diff').style.color = 'red';
         }

       };
```

Comment: inserting snippet which does nothing, makes no sense.